# Injective map from Unit circle to integers $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: measure-theory

Does there exists injective measurable map from $S^1 \to \mathbb{Z}$. I think there can be no continuous injective function. I need injective measurable. Is an injective measurable map between Borel sigama algebra is automatically continuous?

Comment: $S^{1}$ is uncountable. There cannot be any injective map from  it into the integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$S^1$ is uncountable, $\mathbb Z$ is countable. So there can be no injective map from $S^1$ to $\mathbb Z$, measurability doesn't even enter into the picture...

Comment: Can there be a measurable function between them?

Comment: @budi Of course, there's always the trivial ones.